# Get similar links from one site using wget

Tags: grep, wget

I have a site (http://a-site.com) with many links like that. How can I use wget to crawl and grep all similar links to a file?

```
<a href="/user/333333/follow_user" class="btn" rel="nofollow">Follow</a>
```

I tried this but this command only get me all similar links on one page but not recursively follow other links to find similar links.

```
$ wget -erobots=off --no-verbose -r --quiet -O - http://a-site.com 2>&1 | \
  grep -o '['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*/follow_user['"'"'"]'
```

Comment: Cross-posted -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170344/get-similar-links-from-one-site-using-wget#

Comment: Please either delete this one or the one you posted on U&L. It's discouraged from posting the identical Q on multiple SE sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `--accept-regex` option of `wget` rather than piping through `grep` :

```
wget -r --accept-regex '['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*/follow_user['"'"'"]' http://a-site.com
```

(not tested, the regex may need adjustment or specification of `--regex-type` (see `man wget`), and of course add other options you find useful).

Comment: Wow.  Didn't know that wget had that option.  Nice!